# How to read control panel settings of end user client

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis

I have an application in which I have to show the currency input fields by picking up the settings from (**in Windows: Control Panel > Region and Language > Additional Settings > Digit grouping symbol**). For e.g.**1,234,567.89**. If I change my Digit grouping symbol to apostrophe(') then the result would be **1'234'567.89**. For this I am using the following code:

```
    int value = 123456789;
    string output = (value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    Response.Write(output);
```

The above code gives me the output like **123"456"789.00**. Because my Digit grouping symbol is(**"**).

This code works fine on my local, but my actual requirement is to pick each client settings.
I host my code on IIS. And when some other user opens the page it only picks my local settings not the end user settings.  I want to pick the client "**Control Panel**" settings who opens the page and reads the currency input fields as according to his local settings.

To solve this purpose I follow [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771836%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) url. But no help. Please help quick, Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** When I host this page on IIS, it default shows **$123,456,789.00** but my current culture is French and my Digit grouping symbol is(**"**), the output should come **123"456"789;00 €** . Why IIS not picking up my Control Panel settings.

**NOTE:** I also make Enable Client Based Culture set to **True**. I need some quick help.

Comment: Shouldn't this be stored in registry?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it stored in registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > International > sThousand
```